# std::map get previous of lower_bound

Tags: c++11, stdmap, lower-bound

I have a `std::map` as :

```
std::map<unsigned int, char> m_map
{
  std::make_pair (0, 'a'),
  std::make_pair (5, 'b'),
  std::make_pair (10, 'c'),
  std::make_pair (15, 'd'),
};
```

I am using `std::map::lower_bound` to get the iterator to the lower bound.

```
auto lower_bound = m_map.lower_bound(7); // points to  (10, 'c')
```

I want to get the previous element to `lower_bound`. Currently I am iterating over the whole `std::map` and storing the previous element. If lower bound reached then I break the loop.

I want to know, is there a smarter way to get the pointer pointing to the previous element to  `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) iterators are [*bidirectional* iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), which means you can use the `--` operator on them.

As in

```
auto lower_bound = m_map.lower_bound(7); // points to  (10, 'c')
--lower_bound;  // Should now point to (5, 'b')
```

Comment: Ohh. so simple. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it's a bit more complex. You should consider the corner cases in which `lower_bound == m_map.begin()` and m_map is empty